# Returning boolean from SQL function after INSERT command

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple function for updating a column in a table. I want to return boolean to indicate if the update was successful or not.

Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.file_confirm_upload_to_s3(_file_guid uuid )
RETURNS bool AS 
$BODY$
  UPDATE main.file
  SET is_uploaded_to_s3 = true
  WHERE guid = _file_guid
  RETURNING CASE WHEN guid IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE SQL
  VOLATILE
  SECURITY DEFINER;
```

The function returns **TRUE** after a successful update, but it returns **NULL** after an unsuccessful update. Null is falsey, so it'll work for me, but I do wonder how I can solve this a bit cleaner.

An unsuccessful update returns an empty dataset, which yields NULL, hence the return value. How can I test for empty vs. non empty dataset instead of checking the value of the **guid** field?

---

Edit after JGH's answer..
Here is the code that does what I want. I had to switch to **plpgsql** to get access to the `FOUND` variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.file_confirm_upload_to_s3(_file_guid uuid )
RETURNS bool AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
  UPDATE main.file
  SET is_uploaded_to_s3 = true
  WHERE guid = _file_guid;

  RETURN FOUND;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  VOLATILE
  SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `return found;`
This special variable contains a boolean indicating whether one or more row was found using the previous query.
Read its doc 41.5.5 [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html) and example 41-2 [there](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

Comment: Thank you. I had to switch to plpgsql to get access to the found variable. I updated my question with the final code for others to find.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can do this in `SQL` mode

```
...
with c as( -- put your update into cte
    UPDATE main.file
    SET is_uploaded_to_s3 = true
    WHERE guid = _file_guid
    RETURNING guid 
)
select exists(select guid from c);
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the cleaner plpgsql solution better. But I'll keep this trick in mind.